# Can You nest isset() functions in PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

I would like to know if I can nest isset() functions

**Example**

Lets say I have a form like this:

[image]

when someone clicks the view button the isset() function is triggered 
where it displays another form where the user needs to select multiple options like this:

[image]

When the user is done he again needs to click a button **which will trigger a 2nd isset() function nested in the first isset() function**, which will display the team selection.

Is this possibe? or am I using the wrong logic here

Thank you in advance for all the help.

Comment: Not really nested, but do you mean something like, `if(isset($variable_1, $variable_2)){ /* Do something... */ }` ?

Comment: in general.. yes, it's possible to nest it.. like so: `if(isset($a)){if(isset($b)){..}}` but arbitrary levels deep.. that's a bit more complex. You're basically talking about building an expression or predicate engine or decision tree

Comment: I think you should start by reading basics of web development and server side scripting.

Comment: @bansi that is exactly what I am doing. Im working with a book called "PHP The Complete Reference" but it does not mention nor answer my question

Comment: I think you missed the very basics. You never need to nest in your case. once the HTML/form is sent to the browser it is up to the browser to send data to the script. In your situation when you click `View` on the first form it sends data to the script/server and you check if the data is valid and if valid send the second form to the browser.

Comment: Once that form is submitted the data is again sent to the server ( this can be even another script, or the same one) but with different set of data. you need to validate it. There will be no data/reference to what was there in the first form, and if you want to know what was the first form values you should keep it somewhere, like `SESSION` or database. Basically each interaction is different instance of script.

Comment: you man be interested in this link http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming